# pixel to grid mapping for textures

Tags: texturing, uv

Given a texture of some size, I`d like to be able to map the pixel size to an arbitrary unit of measure within my scenes. Is that possible?

E.G.: I have a texture which is 512x512px, and I'd like to tell Blender that 512px from the texture file has to be mapped to 1m (or 1 square from the grid, or just 1 arbitrary unit) in the scene.

I'd like every face with that texture to be UV mapped automatically, so if a surface spans 2x2m, it should tile the texture 2x2 times without me having to do the calculation.

Comment: this may require a custom script

Comment: Unwrapped UV's can be re-sized, distorting any image mapping settings. If you use generated then you can scale the image to taste. A driver could be added to each mapping scale to easily set all usage of the image to the same scale.